# Gravitational waves of an oscillating Schwarzschild black hole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, black-holes, symmetry, gravitational-waves, multipole-expansion

Gravitational waves are produced by an accelerated mass, similar to the production of light waves by an accelerated charge. The amount of gravitational energy released from a rotating object can be obtained by a quadrupole formula.

Consider the ordinary Schwarzschild metric of a non-rotationg and uncharged black hole and instead of the Schwarzschild radius $r_s$ plug in a slightly modified time-dependent radius of the form
$$r_0(t)=r_s+\epsilon \,\sin(\omega t),$$ 
with  $\epsilon\ll r_s$ and $\omega$ constant.

Does such a system emit gravitational waves? If yes, what could be said about their energy?

**EDIT:** Note that the time dependent metric corresponding to $r_0(t)$ is **not** thought to be a solution of Einsteins vaccum equations anymore. Classical solutions of the vacuum equations have a constant mass $M$, but this is not the case in the approach above. This is why here Birkhoff's theorem does not play any role.

Comment: The Birkhoff theorem forbids it

Comment: @СимонТыран A bit more explanation would make a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments Birkhoff’s theorem states that any spherically symmetric solution to the field equations is necessarily static and asymptotically flat. A big implication of this is the fact that the geometry exterior to a spherically symmetric matter distribution such as a star must be static and hence cannot emit gravitational radiation. 
A recent article by [Hill & O’Leary](http://rsos.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/5/4/171109) explicitly shows that seeking radially and time dependent solutions given a spherically symmetric space time confirms Birkhoffs theorem.

Comment: Actually it’s more a consequence of the theorem rather than an assumption. If you take assume a spherically symmetric line element where the metric tensor components are also spherically symmetric then you will recover the Schwarzschild solution. Or, at least a solution that is locally isometric to the Schwarzschild solution.